# Filter div Content by data-attribute with Checkbox using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of cards inside a `div` with class name `.cards-list`
and I want to to filter those cards by data-attribute using checkbox

I tried the following jQuery code but it is not working, after checking checkbox all my cards are hidden and not showing again when I uncheck it

**HTML**

```
<!-- FILTER CHECKBOX -->
<div class="form-check">
   <input class="cardCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="foo">
</div>
<div class="form-check">
   <input class="cardCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="xyz">
</div>

<!-- CARDS LIST I WANT TO FILTER -->
<div class="cards-list mt-2">
    
<div class="card" data-category="foo">
      <div class="card-body">
         <h2>card title</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

 <div class="card" data-category="xyz">
      <div class="card-body">
         <h2>card title</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

 <div class="card" data-category="foo">
      <div class="card-body">
         <h2>card title</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".cardCheckBox").change(function () {
   var value = $(this).val();
   if (this.checked) {
      $(".cards-list.card").filter(function () {
         $(this).toggle($(this).data("category") == value);
      });
   } else {
       $(this).toggle($(this).data("category") == value);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation in code:

```js
// Cache your elements
const $cards = $("[data-category]");
const $cardsCkb = $(".cardCheckBox");

$cardsCkb.on("change", function() {
  
  // Create an Array of checked values
  const checkedArr = $cardsCkb.filter(":checked").get().map(el => el.value);
  
  // Show all and exit if no filter is active
  if (!checkedArr.length) return $cards.removeClass("is-hidden");
    
  // Finally, use jQuery's .toggleClass() and JS's Array.prototype.includes()
  $cards.each(function() {
    const category = $(this).data("category");
    $(this).toggleClass("is-hidden", !checkedArr.includes(category));
  });

});
```

```css
.card.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- FILTER CHECKBOX -->
<div class="form-check">
  <label><input class="cardCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="foo"> foo</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <label><input class="cardCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="xyz"> xyz</label>
</div>

<!-- CARDS LIST I WANT TO FILTER -->
<div class="cards-list mt-2">

  <div class="card" data-category="foo">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2>foo 1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" data-category="xyz">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2>xyz 1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" data-category="foo">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2>foo 2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you this solution works for me, it is also working when selecting multiple checkbox!

Answer (score 0):

You made couple of mistakes.

You need `this.checked == true` in your `if` statement. `this.checked` gives you `true` and `false`, you need to specify what are you looking for.

Also no need for filter, you can do filtering in your element selector (witch was also not targeting right):

```
$(".cards-list  .card[data-category="+value+"]")
```

if you put `.cards-list.card` together it means they are next to each other, in your case `.card` is inside `.cards-list`.

```js
$(".cardCheckBox").change(function () {
   var value = $(this).val();
   //console.log(value);
   if (this.checked == true) {
   //console.log(true);
      $(".cards-list .card[data-category="+value+"]").hide();
      }else{
      $(".cards-list .card[data-category="+value+"]").show();
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- FILTER CHECKBOX -->
<div class="form-check">
   <input class="cardCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="foo">
</div>
<div class="form-check">
   <input class="cardCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="xyz">
</div>

<!-- CARDS LIST I WANT TO FILTER -->
<div class="cards-list mt-2">
    
<div class="card" data-category="foo">
      <div class="card-body">
         <h2>card title foo</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

 <div class="card" data-category="xyz">
      <div class="card-body">
         <h2>card title xyz</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

 <div class="card" data-category="foo">
      <div class="card-body">
         <h2>card title foo</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When both are checked all the cards disappear. So you basically that's introducing a bug ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Well it should be from my understanding of OPs question and code presented? I pozdrav ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Was wondering when Im gonna bump into you. Nice work here on SO ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Will do!

Comment: as @RokoC.Buljan said this solution is not optimal when two or more checkboxes are selected

Comment: @Nasser That may be case in production, but my solution does exactly what you asked for: "I have a list of cards inside a div with class name .cards-list and I want to to filter those cards by data-attribute using checkbox" And i just fixed you code. Next time please elaborate your desired effect more precisely.